# How to trim Characters in ssrs

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012 and I have a field called months which return all the month from January to December . 
But client wants that to be displayed as Jan , Feb , Mar,..,Dec first 3 letters of every month , I tried few works around in ssrs but my expression is not working. Can anyone help me with it. I cannot change into database as we want to display on Screen as full.

Comment: Provide the expression you tried?
How is the month returned from the stored procedure? Is it a number or text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can get the [MONTHNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxbsw165(v=vs.90).aspx) of a date by using

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!myDate.Value))
```

And take the first 3 letters of this using [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
=Left(MonthName(Month(Fields!myDate.Value)), 3)
```

**Option 1b**

You can also use [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx) on any string

```
=Left(Fields!myString.Value, 3)
```

**Option 2**

Format the textbox or expression containing the date to have the [format MMM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#MMM_Specifier)

```
="MMM"
```

Comment: Left One Worked for me as I am getting the Month from the Database , thank You so much @jonnus once again :)